# Magento new store view as subpath of URL

Tags: magento

I was advised by an SEO specialist that I should add a /aus/ sub-folder to my Magento installation for geo-target specific purposes.

So what I am trying to achieve is to add the same version of my store in a **/aus/** sub-folder.

So basically that it would look something like this:

- [www.mystore.com/](http://www.mystore.com/) <- my current store
- [www.mystore.com/aus/](http://www.mystore.com/aus/) <- for geo-targeting specific purposes

I do not want to run the /aus/ version on a separate installation or separate language, basically it should just add /aus/ to my current store and replicate all links there.

What is the best way to have this handled? Some recommendations or advises would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avoiding duplicate content (http://mystore.com/article.html and http://mystore.com/aus/article.html) is also recommended as common SEO practice. You SEO specialists advice clashes with this if you have only one language in your shop it's evident from the "meta" tags referring to accepted language. Crawler bots get geo according to IP & TLD.

Comment: Thank you for your insights Mihai Stancu - apart from what you have pointed out do you have a solution on how to get it accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the store into the URL via configuration? Magento already has configuration for this. See `System > Configuration > General > Web > Add Store Code to Urls`.

Instead of `yourwebsite.com/customer/account`, it will now generate URLs like `yourwebsite.com/<your_store_code>/customer/account`.

Do note that all of your custom templates and modules should properly use the getUrl() Magento methods to build URL, otherwise these URL will not contain the storecode and end up not working.

Comment: You had any luck with it TheDave?

Comment: Great! Works superb, just wondering if you know how  to have this disabled for the default store.

Comment: You can't. It's a global option.

Answer (score 0):

add a new website "aus"

and then create new folder with index.php that run "aus" store

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply leo - I have tried your approach but once I open /aus/ it results in : /public_html/mag/aus/app/Mage.php was not found